# Connecting DbFit to Postgres DB on the AWS Cloud?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, database-connection, dbfit

I have a Postgres DB which is on AWS RDS Cloud server and I wish to connect to it using DbFit.

What I have is a URL (for the Server DNS Host), which resolves to the Postgres DB, along with the User and Password:

```
Sample URL (not current, will not work):
jdbc:postgresql://abcdrdp000525.cgvtcmc.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3333/abc0005

User: abcdef_test
Password: AGagGAHKDJkBNDJHNH1234HSJ9djdk
```

I want to create a DbFit connection string with this, which is of the format:

```
!|dbfit.PostgresTest|

!|Connect|<DB Host Server>|<User>|<Password>|<DB Name/Table Name>|

!|Connect|<DB Host Server>|abcdef_test|AGagGAHKDJkBNDJHNH1234HSJ9djdk|<DB Name/Table Name>|
```

Does anyone have an idea of what would be the "DB Host Server" and the "DB Name/Table Name", from the information supplied above?

Any other suggestions on how to connect and run queries from the Command Line on a AWS RDS Cloud system, using Postgres DB?